# Valve extender snapped off

Tags: valves

Yesterday I crashed, and somehow the front wheel landed on a rock or something that made my valve extender break. The bottom part of it is still stuck in the valve it extended. It's a tubular tire so just changing tube is not an option.

Any suggestions on how to get it out?

[image: Image of the problem]

[image]

Comment: It looks from the picture like you could get a dremel or a needle file at it without damaging the rim. The you could make a screwdriver slot. Would that help? Does it seem feasible with the wheel on front of you?

Comment: It seems to me that you should just drill the thing out.  Because spokes will be in the way going inside-out, probably you'd want go in from the outside.

Comment: Can you get the tube and tyre off at all?

Comment: That silver ring - is that a grommit in the wheel for protecting the valve stem? Or is it part of the valve extender?   If the first I'd try turning it with pliers.   Otherwise buy the correct size easy-out screw extractor and thread it into the hole.

Comment: Not sure how the rock caused that without damaging other things, but maybe there was some pre-existing damage.   Your other option is to force the tyre/tube off the rim, which shouldn't be hard.  You may need to puncture the tube to let the air out if its still holding air.

Comment: Can you add some specs about the tyre and extender?It is difficult to tell what that silver ring is or how it's related to an extender.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you see there is not the extender, but the broken-off valve.

Comment: Is the tube holding air still ? If no, your valve has broken off and it should be simply a matter of changing  the tyre.     If yes, the valve is closed.  Consider flatting the tyre to relax it and get the tyre off.

Comment: Yeah, remove the tire.

Comment: @pantani this is a fascinating problem.  Please do let us know how it worked out for you.

Comment: ended up at the LBS and they are skilled at the black magic of bicycle repairing

Answer (score 2):

Cover the rim all around the valve with a thick layer of duct tape until the tape is almost level with the exposed surface of the valve. Then put one more piece of duct tape over the top of the valve.

Draw a line across the top pf the valve with a marker pen.

Get a miniature hack-saw and **very gently** start cutting a groove down into the top of the valve (perpendicular to the rim). Use a competent friend to hold the wheel upright and very still while doing this (may even help to add more duct tape to hold the wheel down on the floor). Once the groove is deep enough to hold the blade, remove enough of the duct tape so you can see how far down the rim is.

Keep cutting down to the limit of your confidence (i.e. don't cut into the rim).

Now use a thin-ended screw-driver to unscrew the valve. If the cut is to narrow to easily fit your screw-driver into, use a narrower blade (like a bread knife) until you have the valve down almost flush with the rim.

If that is all too scary, take it to your LBS.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a very straightforward job for an easy out.[image]

Comment: I tried this but I couldnt make it work

Answer (score 1):

I've never faced this situation, so I can only speculate. That said:

1. Remove tire.
2. Apply lubricant around the edge of extender remnant to facilitate removal--something like WD40 should suffice.
3. Attempt to pop out the extender remnant with your thumb.
4. When that doesn't work, set the rim on two pieces of scrap wood with the valve opening between them; have a friend hold the rim in place while you tap on the extender remnant with a mallet. You may need something to drive it all the way out, like a large nail or a nailsetter.

Comment: its threaded so taping it out might be a bit difficult

Comment: I take your point. Lube and needlenose vise-grips maybe.